# UML method definition too long to fit in the class box

Tags: uml

I have a constructor that receives multiple parameters so it is a line a bit long. I'm working on the UML diagram for the class but I'm not sure if I could break the line and continue on the next one so that the class box does not take that much room. Probably this is something that has been asked before, but I haven't found a good reference on what to do in this case.

```java
public Product(String name, int code, int price, int quantity, 
           int minQuantity, int maxQuantity) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.minimumQuantity = minQuantity;
    this.maximumQuantity = maxQuantity;
}
```

Comment: What's your purpose? Do you need to have the parameters listed or not? Are you building a model or just drawing a diagram?

Answer (score 1):

The UML specification does not specify whether wrapping the text on multiple lines is allowed or not. Because it's not forbidden, I would say it is allowed.

Personally, I would not show long parameter lists in class diagrams. A class diagram should primarily give an overview of classes and their relationships. To publish the details of the operations, it is usually better to generate textual documentation from the source code.

9.6.4 of UML 2.5.1 (page 118) states

> The parameter list may be suppressed.

or even better, you may suppress the complete list of operations.

9.2.4.1 of UML 2.5.1 (page 101) states

> Any compartment may be suppressed.